# BeautifulSoup "encode("utf-8")

Tags: python, python-3.x, utf-8, character-encoding, python-unicode

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup   
import urllib.request    

link = ('https://mywebsite.org')  
req = urllib.request.Request(link, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
url = urllib.request.urlopen(req).read()

soup =  BeautifulSoup(url, "html.parser")  
body = soup.find_all('div', {"class":"wrapper"})

print(body)
```

Hi guys, I have a problem with this code. If I run it it come the error

> UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u2022' in position 138: character maps to

I tryed to search and I found that I had to add

> .encode("utf-8")

but if I add it come the error

> AttributeError: 'ResultSet' object has no attribute 'encode'

How I can resolve this?

I'm sorry for my english but I'm italian :)

Comment: Can you please provide the whole error stack instead of just the last line of the error? Also, where did you add the `.encode("utf-8")` ? Please put the code after you add the encode() method too.

Comment: In future, please provide a full stacktrace (Your English is fine btw).

Comment: Please edit your post to include the entire error message, including the backtrace. For future reference, please read [ask] and [mcve] to see what sort of questions elicit useful answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're on Windows and trying to print to the console. The `print()` is throwing the exception.

The Windows console only natively supports 8bit code pages, so anything outside of your region will break (despite what people say about `chcp 65001`).

You need to install and use https://github.com/Drekin/win-unicode-console. This module talks at a low-level to the console API, giving support for multi-byte characters.

Alternatively, don't print to the console and write your output to a file, opened with an encoding. For example:

```
with open("myoutput.log", "w", encoding="utf-8") as my_log:
    my_log.write(body)
```