# Python: UnicodeEncodeError when printing accented characters

Tags: python, unicode, utf-8, decode, encode

Using Python 2.7.11

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
print 'ÁÉŐÜŐ'
print u'ÁÉÖÜŐ'
```

With the following result:

```
├ü├ë┼É├£┼É
    Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "C:\Users\RaseR\Desktop\testing.py", line 4, in <module>
            print u'├ü├ë├û├£┼É'
        File "C:\Python27\lib\encodings\cp850.py", line 12, in encode
            return codecs.charmap_encode(input,errors,encoding_map)
    UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character u'\u0150' in 
    position 4: character maps to <undefined>
```

If necessary:

Notepad++ with encoding UTF-8

Windows 10 Console w/ Lucida Console Font

Comment: It working fine for me in IDLE ide..

Comment: It looks like your console is using [codepage 850](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_850), not UTF-8. You need to change that.

Comment: Have you checked some of the hits on stackoverflow when searching for "[python] print UnicodeEncodeError"?

Comment: @mkiever Yes, I did.

Comment: @PM2Ring Yeah, my console is using cp850. But if I change it to cp65001 it works well, except on other computers.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [BeautifulSoup "encode("utf-8")](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36086399/beautifulsoup-encodeutf-8)

Comment: The right tool to solve such problems is your debugger. You should step through your code line-by-line before asking on Stack Overflow. For more help, please read [How to debug small programs (by Eric Lippert)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). At a minimum, you should [edit] your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example that reproduces your problem, along with the observations you made in the debugger.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

When you `print`, you are printing to standard output. Standard output uses some encoding and everything has to be converted to that encoding.

In my case:

```
>>> sys.stdout.encoding
'cp852'
>>> u'\u0150'.encode(sys.stdout.encoding)
'\x8a'
>>> print u'\u0150'
Ő
>>> print '\x8a'
Ő
```

In your case, it seems that the Ő character does not exist in the encoding used by stdout, so the conversion fails. There is no way to print that.

You can encode it manually, specifying what to do with characters which cannot be encoded:

```
>>> print u'\u0150'.encode(sys.stdout.encoding, 'replace')
Ő
```

With a character which it cannot encode:

```
>>> print u'\u0150\u1234'.encode(sys.stdout.encoding, 'replace')
Ő?
```